# MySQL Summing & Counting Child Values in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

```
 BOOKINGS TABLE
 id | price | anotherVal 
 -----------------------------
 1  | 10000 | *          
 2  | 20000 | *         
 3  | 1000  | *          
 4  | 8000  | *  


 BOOKING PAYMENTS TABLE
 id | bookingId  | amount | currencyId | mxnAmount 
 --------------------------------------------------
 1  | 1          | 100.00 | 1          | 100.00        
 2  | 1          | 300.00 | 3          | 6400.00    
 3  | 2          | 500.21 | 1          | 500.21  
 4  | 4          | 123.95 | 6          | 
 4  | 4          | 800.00 | 1          | 800.00
```

I need to get all BOOKINGS_TABLE columns and then for each booking add up the mxnAmount column, but also the result should tell if all rows in BOOKING_PAYMENTS_TABLE had an mxnAmount so i can know if the mxnAmount is final or there's some rows left to be updated, i have a query that works for the first part:

```
SELECT b.*, SUM(p.mxnAmount) FROM bookings b LEFT JOIN bookingPayments p ON b.id = p.bookingId GROUP BY b.id
```

I figured i could make us of COUNT() to count all rows in BOOKING_PAYMENTS_TABLE but then how can i get the number for the rows that have an mxnAMOUNT?

```
SELECT b.*, SUM(p.mxnAmount), COUNT(p.id) FROM bookings b LEFT JOIN bookingPayments p ON b.id = p.bookingId GROUP BY b.id
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT b.*, SUM(p.mxnAmount), COUNT(p.id), COUNT(pp.id) FROM bookings b LEFT JOIN bookingPayments p ON b.id = p.bookingId LEFT JOIN bookingPayments pp ON b.id = pp.bookingId WHERE pp.mxnAmount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY b.id
```

But then the query returns only bookings that have all their payments rows with an mxnAmount, any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I figured i could make us of COUNT() to count all rows in BOOKING_PAYMENTS_TABLE but then how can i get the number for the rows that have an mxnAMOUNT?

Just `COUNT()` that particular column: this gives you the number of non-`null` values in the column for each group:

```
SELECT b.*, SUM(p.mxnAmount), COUNT(p.id), COUNT(p.mxnAmount)
FROM bookings b 
LEFT JOIN bookingPayments p ON b.id = p.bookingId 
GROUP BY b.id
```

If you want to know if any `mxmamount` in the group is missing, you can do:

```
MAX(p.id IS NOT NULL AND p.mxnAmount IS NULL) has_missing_mxnAmount
```

Comment: Thank you very much!